# MySQL Table does not support optimize

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My Wordpress tables appear to be in need of optimization so I looked into the commmand OPTIMIZE TABLE .  When I run the command I get the following results:

> Table does not support optimize, doing
>   recreate + analyze instead

The tables are built using the Wordpress 2.91 installer and haven't been modified at all.

1. Is this normal?
2. How can I optimize
   my database to keep things working
   correctly?

Comment: Did you get your table optimized?

Answer (score 5):

Have you found the MySQL documentation?  It's extensive and useful.

When you run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` against InnoDB tables it outputs the `Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead` message.

From the documentation:

> OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in the clustered index.

[MySQL 5.1 OPTIMIZE TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)

Comment: With this in mind, be certain as to your engine before enabling `skip-innodb` as I suggested in your earlier post.

Comment: Funny, I searched many times for support on this topic and didn't find that info...  So, actually, the mySQL documentation isn't really that useful....

Even so, I still don't see an answer to my question on how to keep my database working correctly without being able to optimize the database...

Comment: The message indicates that it *is* optimizing the table.  The reason why it's so verbose is because it's essentially a shortcut for the alter table statement, which is what had to be used instead  in earlier versions of MySQL because `OPTIMIZE TABLE` couldn't be run against InnoDB.  Why do you believe you need to optimize the table for your database to operate correctly?

Answer (score 5):

You can optimize an InnoDB table by doing

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE='InnoDB';
```

This will create a copy of the original table drop the original table and put the new table in it's place.

There is some [additional information here](http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/76-An-InnoDB-tutorial.html) which includes things you should be aware of.

Also [in the MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html). See the comment by Dathan Pattishall on May 25 2004 4:41pm about half way down the page.

Although this should be safe to do you should make and test a backup first.

Comment: This produces the exact same results as running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` against an InnoDB table in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible

use a wp database plugin  like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dbmanager/

& activate the plugin

& go to the page & click on optimize database
it will optimize your database

No need of entering any sql logins. It fetches from wp-config.php

Answer (score 2):

OPTIMIZE does work for InnoDB. At least it does now. This is 5.6 documentation:

For InnoDB tables, OPTIMIZE TABLE is mapped to ALTER TABLE, which rebuilds the table to update index statistics and free unused space in the clustered index.

Read : [Optimize Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html)